# Is there any log limit for printing payload in mule-3 or Mule-4

Tags: logging, log4j, mule, mulesoft, mule-esb

I am trying to print huge json with  base64 content in the logger. I am suspecting that entire payload is not getting printed. Because json closed tags are not appearing at  the end of payload. take a look at the payload that is getting printed

```
 {"emailSubject": "TEST : (DocID=000100) (UPI=xxxxyy) Request : Arun, Prema","status": "sent","compositeTemplates": [{"serverTemplates": [{"sequence": 1,"templateId": "0D8DA18B"}],"document":{"name" : " LOA","display" : "inline","documentId" : "1","documentBase64":"JVBERi0.....................................
```

and the closing double quotes are also not there at the ending. what can I do to print entire payload. base64 content is at the ending tag "documentBase64". we are using mule on-prem not using cloudhub logging

Comment: Aren't you seeing the `... [truncated]` in the log?

Comment: no i am not seeing ..[truncates message] . we are using mule one prem server and splunk see logs

Comment: How big is your payload?

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool for that purpose. Using a logger to print big payloads may cause issues like high memory usage, high CPU usage, or truncated/corrupted message. The expected usage of a logger like log4j2 is to print log messages to track what the application is doing, not auditing huge payloads. If you want to send payloads somewhere, like a file or Splunk, use a connector. You could find an existing one or need to create your your own.